# I am getting error while working with relation in stimulsoft report

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

Error is : Additional information: Parent Data Source 'EmpDetails' and
Child Data Source 'SalaryDetails' is not located in one DataSet and
can't be used in relation 'EmpSal'! You can use property CacheAllData of
report to cache this Data Source to one DataSet.

```
 public class Employeedetails
 {
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string JoiningDate { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ContractType { get; set; }
    public string LastWorkingDate { get; set; }
    public string LengthofService { get; set; }
    public string ReasonforExit { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeSalaryDetails
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string AllowanceName { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
} 

report.CacheAllData = true;                      
report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reports/ReportTemplates/FinalSettlementReport - Copy.mrt"));
report.RegData("EmpDetails", EmployeeDetailsList);
report.RegData("SalaryDetails", EmployeeSalaryList);
```

[this is report designin in stimulsoft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElHDx.png)

Comment: Just an observation, I don't know if this matters or not but I would put the CacheAllData = True AFTER loading the report

Comment: Hello Steve your observation is correct. After putting CacheAllData = True AFTER loading the report it works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reports/ReportTemplates/FinalSettlementReport - Copy.mrt"));
                report.RegData("EmpDetails", EmployeeDetailsList);
                report.RegData("SalaryDetails", EmployeeSalaryList);                
                report.RegBusinessObject("SchoolInfoModel", schoolInfo);
                report.CacheAllData = true;
```

after changing the position of report.CacheAllData = true; after the loading report done it works without error.
'

Answer (score 0):

report.CacheAllData = true;
report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reports/ReportTemplates/FinalSettlementReport - Copy.mrt"));

//Use this.

report.Compile();

report.RegData("EmpDetails", EmployeeDetailsList);
report.RegData("SalaryDetails", EmployeeSalaryList);